# What is the necessary Math skills needed for a particular field?

Tags: math

Do you have an overview of what kind of Math is most useful for which field? For example, if a linux kernel developer, what type of math knowledge does one programmer need? For a driver developer, what type of Math is needed? It seems to me that except for computer science related fields and game programming, do other IT fields need hardcore Math?

Comment: Knowing basic arithmetic is a must. Some algebra is useful. Having played with math concepts can help, especially when doing functional programming. Beyond this, it depends on your programming field. Basic geometry is useful and often unknown to programmers, looking at the numerous questions about 5th grade geometry here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<metaphor>`Having a degree in math, a math hammer makes a lot of problems look like programming nails.`<metaphor/>`

Here are some math hammers:

- *linear algebra* to solve near-singular matrices in NMR Spectroscopy
  (medicine)
- *statistics* to test the
  quality of a data feed (see
  [Experiment design](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5873/experiment-design-for-proportion))
- *combinatorics*    to figure out how to
  break down power    sets
  (Engineering)
- more *combinatorics*    to count drug
  combinations (see    [N-sided
  dice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5934/odds-of-rolling-doubles-or-triples-given-n-6-sided-dice/)) (Medicine again)
- *complex arithmetic* to look at Mandelbrot sets (school)
- *Monte Carlo*    method (physics,
  financial simulations, and a bar bet)
- *calculus* to solve    equations
  (finance)
- *Boolean logic*    (crosses    all
  programming disciplines)

You might think that a given math course is a waste of time. However, if you learn from the course, you'll know which tool to dust off and when you need and use it!

Answer (score 3):

Discrete math and binary and logic math of course needed in all fields.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're doing a specific type of development that involves mathematical calculations, most programming areas do not really require a lot of math knowledge (exceptions below).  However, it's very common in hiring to look for a strong math background because there tends to be a high correlation between strong math skills and strong programming skills--good organization to solve complex mathematical problems indicates good organization to solve complex programming problems.

There have been some studies that actually look at alternative ways to teach programming with very different results.  For example, looking at correlations between creative writing and programming, look at people with very good creative writing skills, and teach them to program as if the program is telling a story, not solving a problem.  This has shown to also produce very good programmers, often with a different take on problems.

Exceptions to when math is really required is for things like video codec implementations, statistics required for advanced reporting, or any type of low-level 3D work not using an API that abstracts it all away (which is most commonly the case).

Comment: I don't agree. Most great mathematicians that I know are very poor programmers, even if their everyday work is about writing programs. There is a strong correlation between being good at math and *knowing how to solve problems* though. Being a good programmer does not mean being a good problem solver, it is more a handcraftman skill. There are specific areas where *both* are needed (anything which involves eg. simulating stuff), and people with both skills are very hard to find (and usually already work for big companies like Google).

Comment: @Alexandre C., I agree that it's hard to find people with both skills.  Most CS students that are very good will enter the job force and then never actively look for another job--they may switch jobs through networking, but often will never quit their job without having a new one lined up and often will never show up on Monster.com or other job search sites.  That's particularly why good big companies like Google and Microsoft have very big pushes to hire good candidates right out of school.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) provide essential tools in algorithm construction.